# Calculate max (i.e. the largest number) of certain cells in a row conditionally for a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will find the maximum value (i.e. the largest) for specific columns in row.

Figure 1:

[image]

For example, In FIGURE 1 I have shown a simple example table ranging A1 to K12. Where the top 2 rows represent ‘Height’ and ‘Year’ respectively. And they are always in ascending order. The figure shows 2 years data and I am trying to create the maximum for each height between years. I have highlighted in red text what I am trying to do. For example, cell L3 is the Max of B3 and G3 (i.e. =MAX(B3,G3)) and similarly all the cells for range L3:P12 in red are the maximum values for each heights. 
I know I can do this easily just by manually calculating using Max(cell1,cell2) function or by using the following Macro:

```
Sub test()
    Range("G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("L3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-10],RC[-5])"
    Range("L3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L3:P3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("L3:P3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L3:P12")
    Range("L3:P12").Select
End Sub
```

But my actual table is far more larger with many more years of data with more heights and I will be running this in a loop for many spreadsheets. There for the number of rows and columns can vary.  So I am just wondering how I can adopt a dynamic argument that will dynamically calculate the max based on the top two rows (i.e. height and year). 
I was thinking if any way I could set a range for the top row as the height will be always increasing until the next year when it restart from the lowest value again. My plan was to then try to put some conditions to calculate the max values and autofill the range. But I am just not able to even define the range as I am strugling to logically plan this code. The following is what I have tried and I would really appreciate any guidance on how logically I could achieve this problem. Many thanks in Advance!

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, r As Range
LR = Range("1" & Columns.Count).End(xlToRight)
For i = 1 To LR
    If Range("1" & i).Value > 10 Then
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Set r = Range("1" & i)
        Else
            Set r = Union(r, Range("1" & i))
        End If
    End If
Next i
r.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: For every year will there be only one value for a certain height? If so, I think this is possible by formula. If you are into VBA, possible as well but you need to clarify my first question.

Comment: This can be done with an array formula - but the performance will depend on the amount of data... so can you provide more information about the scale of your real life data? How many rows? How many different heights? How many years? Another option could be to write your own `MAXIF` worksheet function - this would be simple to write and potentially easier to understand and maintain...

Comment: apologies for the late reply. @ L42 yes for every year there are one values for certain height.

Comment: @ Captain; the total amount of rows wont exceed more then 25, and the number of height could be 10 - about 200 (with steps of 10 each time like 10,20,30, ...200). and the years could be about 5 to maximum 10 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the unlimited possibility of height values, using a class was the best solution that I could think of for now. Hopefully this provides a good foundation to build from.

In a class module named 'HeightClass':

```
Option Explicit

Dim rngRangeStore As Range
Dim sValueStore As String

Public Property Set rngRange(rngInput)
    Set rngRangeStore = rngInput
End Property

Public Property Get rngRange() As Range
    Set rngRange = rngRangeStore
End Property

Public Property Let sValue(sInput As String)
    sValueStore = sInput
End Property

Public Property Get sValue() As String
    sValue = sValueStore
End Property
```

Then in a standard Module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_Max()
Dim lRecord As Long, lRange As Long, lLastRecord As Long, lLastColumn As Long
Dim colRanges As New Collection
Dim clsRange As HeightClass

    'Find Last used column in the year row
    lLastColumn = Rows(2).Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    'Find last used row in column 1
    lLastRecord = Columns(1).Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For lRange = 2 To lLastColumn
        On Error Resume Next
        Set clsRange = Nothing
        Set clsRange = colRanges(Trim$(Cells(1, lRange).Value))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not clsRange Is Nothing Then

            'Add to existing range
            Set clsRange.rngRange = Union(clsRange.rngRange, Cells(1, lRange))
        Else

            'Add range to colletion in order of smallest to largest
            Set clsRange = New HeightClass
            Set clsRange.rngRange = Cells(1, lRange)
            clsRange.sValue = Cells(1, lRange).Value
            If colRanges.Count = 0 Then
                colRanges.Add Item:=clsRange, Key:=clsRange.sValue
            Else
                For lRecord = 1 To colRanges.Count
                    If clsRange.sValue < colRanges(lRecord).sValue Then
                        colRanges.Add Item:=clsRange, Key:=clsRange.sValue, Before:=colRanges(lRecord).sValue
                        Exit For
                    ElseIf lRecord = colRanges.Count Then
                        colRanges.Add Item:=clsRange, Key:=clsRange.sValue, After:=colRanges(lRecord).sValue
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next lRecord
            End If
        End If
    Next lRange

    'Place height headers
    For lRange = 1 To colRanges.Count
        With Cells(1, lLastColumn + lRange)
            .Value = colRanges(lRange).sValue
            .Font.Color = vbRed
        End With
    Next lRange

    'Process each record
    For lRecord = 3 To lLastRecord
        For lRange = 1 To colRanges.Count
            With Cells(lRecord, lLastColumn + lRange)
                .Value = Application.Max(colRanges(lRange).rngRange.Offset(lRecord - 1))
                .Font.Color = vbRed
                .NumberFormat = "0.00"
            End With
        Next lRange
    Next lRecord
End Sub
```

This is written to perform the desired process on whatever sheet is in focus.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dustin, it works great for me and I have altered to adopt to my actual datasets with the rest of tasks that I am trying to do. I never used the class module before and it is something completely new for me and your example really gave me a good idea of the uses of the class module, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

So the array formula (enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)version would be, in `L3` etc.:

```
=MAX(IF($B$1:$K$1=L$1,$B3:$K3,""))
```

It says:

- look in the headers `$B$1:$K$1` to check a match for your column's height (`=L$1`)
- if it matches, take the value `,$B3:$K3`
- otherwise ignore it `,""`
- take the `MAX` of those non-ignored values

I tried this with 100 columns (5 heights * 20 years) and 1000 rows of `RAND` produced random numbers and the recalculation time was negligible

Comment: thanks for your help, I understand you method and it works for me but the other option sutes my need better as I could build up from this to add other codes that I want the worksheet to perform. But thanks a lot for you advice, It will be useful for the future